# #include <CEGUI/RendererModules/Ogre/CEGUIOgreRenderer.h> doesn't include ogre headers correctly

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, ogre3d

Using Ubuntu 10.10 I have compiled and installed the latest Ogre and CEGUI libraries.

I can #include  for example but when I try to add the CEGUI headers I have issues.

```
#include <CEGUI/RendererModules/Ogre/CEGUIOgreRenderer.h>
```

This in turn includes OgreBlendMode.h and OgreTextureUnitState.h but doesn't have the OGRE/ in front of it.

Do I just have to go through these cegui headers and adjust them all or is there a way I can rebuild cegui to use OGRE/whatever in the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the OGRE directory in your default include path.